# Can't modify a 2D array of an unknown size within a fucntion in C

Tags: c, function, multidimensional-array, parameter-passing

I new to C, and I just can't figure out how to modify a 2D array in a function.
Here's the code I tried:

```
void init_matrix(int **M) {
    M[0][0] = 1;
}

int main(void) {    
    int M[3][3];    
    init_matrix(M, 3);

    return 0;
}
```

(Please note that this code is voluntarily stripped down in order to focus on the issue, **I need my function to be able to work on arrays of a globally unknown size (though it could be a parameter of the function)**)

When I try to run this, it just gets stuck... The debugger says it's a problem of right to write in this memory slot.

**How would you write the `init_matrix` function in the C spirit ?**
Why can't I write in my matrix ?

I would like to use as few "advanced" concepts and function as possible.

Thanks in advance =)

Comment: You have got to listed to your compiler. `void init_matrix(int **M)` and `init_matrix(M, 3);` -- what's wrong with this picture? "Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)."

Answer (score 2):

An array is not a pointer. You need to give the dimensions of the array when you pass it as a function parameter.

```
void    init_matrix(size_t x, size_t y, int matrix[x][y])
{
    for (size_t i = 0 ; i < x ; ++i)
    {
        for (size_t j = 0 ; j < y ; ++j)
            matrix[i][j] = 1;
    }
}

int     main(void)
{
    int matrix[5][3];

    init_matrix(5, 3, matrix);

    return (0);
}
```

The function `init_matrix()` takes as parameters the dimensions, then the array (this order is important here). The "double loop" is a classic for running through a "2D memory area" like our array.
(Note that you can forget the first dimension,

`void  init_matrix(size_t x, size_t y, int matrix[][y])`

also works)